# is there a way to get images from client and upload it to cloudinary using node js?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, cloudinary

i am trying to get an image from client and upload the image to cloudinary but i keep getting an error of empty file.. Please someone should help me out, i have been trying this for days and i have used similar questions and answer from on here but still can't find a solution to solve the problem. I am using multer package to get my image from the client which is displayed at my request.file. this is my code below

```
const image = request.file;
// console.log(request.body);
console.log(image);

let tempPath = image.path;
let targetPath = path.resolve("./server/public/uploads/", image.originalname);

let src = fs.createReadStream(tempPath);
let dest = fs.createWriteStream(targetPath);
let result = src.pipe(dest);


cloudinary.config({
  api_key: "xxxxxxxx",
  api_secret: "xxxxxxxx",
  secure: true,
  cloud_name: "xxxxxxx",
});

try {
  const imageUrl = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
    result.path,
    function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("error");
        return;
      }
      console.log("result");
    }
  );
  console.log({ imageUrl });
} catch (error) {
  console.log({ error });
}
response.send(image);
};
```

this is my result below with the error message i am getting

```
    {
  fieldname: 'image',
  originalname: 'defaultLogo.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  destination: './public/uploads/',
  filename: '186443a54df4c23b34cf0034e6ae8bfb',
  path: 'public/uploads/186443a54df4c23b34cf0034e6ae8bfb',
  size: 4308
}
error
{ error: { message: 'Empty file', name: 'Error', http_code: 400 } }
```

Comment: it looks like you are upload from buffer but not using the right upload method, please see the resolution on https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007581379-Correct-way-of-uploading-from-buffer- and check if it helps.